# Is there anyway to handle onPause() for whole application instead of each activity?

Tags: android

recently I have created an application which has many activities inside it. In `onPause()`, I need to do a specific task. This task is the same for all activites. I wonder that is there anyway to handle onPause() one time for the whole application instead of overring onPause() for every activity many times?

For example, I want to set boolean variable called `Online` to false in onPause(). Because my application has 10 activities, so I have override onPause() 10 times. It is very inconvenient. Therefore, I would like to find a more effective way to do that.

In any case, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

1. you can use a `BaseActivity` class, then extends other Activity with it. Now, you can add your code in BaseActivity `onPause()`.
2. you can add `Application.lifeCycleCallback`, this callback can receive all Activity Life Cycle, and add your code in listener `onPause()`

Comment: Can you give me some examples or keyworks to search for example on google?

Answer (score 0):

from [谢金龙](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10705478/%e8%b0%a2%e9%87%91%e9%be%99) answer

1). Create your base activity

```
open class BaseActivity  :AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onPause() {
        //handle onPause here
        super.onPause()
    }
}
```

2). In any activity

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```